# Deleting '404' errors in my source.list

Tags: apt

I run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

which returns these failures at the end:

```
W: Failed to fetch httpe://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Protocol httpe not supported or disabled in libcurl
W: Failed to fetch httpe://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Protocol httpe not supported or disabled in libcurl
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I fix this problem? I've looked all around and can't seem to find an answer.

After running

```
lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:    trusty
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `lsb_release -a`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One simple command, `httpe` isn't a valid protocol:

```
sudo sed -i 's/httpe:/http:/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

---

And now, it seems, that you have Trusty installed and Raring repositories in your `sources.list`

If you do not need this repositories, then remove the lines with

```
sudo sed -i '/raring/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: I ran those commands but still have 404 faliures showing up

Comment: still having 404 errors

Comment: @A.B. I think there is something to do with the EOL Raring.

Comment: @P.-H.Lin Yes, raring =(

Comment: Updated my answer again

Comment: And don't forget the `sudo apt-get update` ;)

Comment: I just went back to a default source.list and ran sudo apt-get update which returned failures after it loaded headers but no mention of 404 before the headers loaded however i did get "err" on a bunch of them..for some reason the computer keeps telling me "httpe" and I think it is supposed to be "https" is this what you were trying to change for me before? Im not saavy with ubuntu sorry

Comment: No, I mean `http` and I mean all things, as described in my answer.

Comment: my computer is trying to use httpe instead of https is what im saying...no one anywhere that ive seen has ever encountered this problem even...if i could get it to think it was https instead of e i think my problem might be solved but i wouldnt know where to start

Comment: Again, it isn't `https` it's `http`. And give me the output of the command mentioned in my comment below your answer.

Comment: ran the sudo sed -i '/raring/d' /etc/apt/sources.list command then sudo apt-get update once again still having problems current failures look like this W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found
and : Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: `sudo sed -i 's/old-releases.ubuntu.com/archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: and that fix my problem! shweet thanks bro mucho gracias!

Comment: Shouldn't Raring get removed automatically when you upgrade to Saucy/Trusty?  Even if you edit `sources.list` by hand, Ubuntu still disables everything it doesn't recognize during the distribution upgrade.  The only explanation is that someone/thing manually added Raring back to the list *after* the upgrade, which seems rather insane to me.  What package does this, so that I can never install it?